# Which hook to use to save order meta data before email notifications are send in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm looking for a **Woocommerce action hook** (or filter, I'm not sure) where I can update the shipping & billing address before the New Order email notification is sent.

Right now, I'm using the `woocommerce_before_thankyou` to update order meta.

The order is saved with correct address that I want to save, but the email is not displaying the correct address.

Here is the example code, similar with what I'm doing:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_save_user_meta');

function checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $my_custom_address = 'My custom address';
    
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_1',  $my_custom_address );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_1',  $my_custom_address );
}
```

Any advice on which hook to use for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` or the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` action hook.

So you would get:

```php
/**
 * Action hook to adjust order before save.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
function action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {    
    // Some value
    $my_custom_address = 'My custom address';

    // Update meta data
    $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_address_1', $my_custom_address );
    $order->update_meta_data( '_shipping_address_1', $my_custom_address );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 );
```

OR

```php
/**
 * Action hook fired after an order is created used to add custom meta to the order.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id, $data ) {    
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {     
        // Some value
        $my_custom_address = 'My custom address';

        // Update meta data
        $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_address_1', $my_custom_address );
        $order->update_meta_data( '_shipping_address_1', $my_custom_address );

        // Save
        $order->save();
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, nighter `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` or the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` action hook worked. Order confirmation emails were still showing the original shipping address.

I needed to use `woocommerce_email_customer_details`in order to get the emails to show the right shipping address.

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);
function email_confirmation_display_order_items( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email): void {
    
    $order->update_meta_data('_shipping_address_1', {{'the value here'}} );
    $order->update_meta_data('_shipping_address_2', {{'the value here'}} );
    $order->update_meta_data('_shipping_postcode', {{'the value here'}});
    $order->update_meta_data('_shipping_city', {{'the value here'}} );

    $order->save();
}
```